# loading icon on asp.net page disappear once the page loads

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am asked to fix someone else code that was written  while ago. Below is the code:

```
<script>
    $(document).bind( 'mobileinit', function(){
        $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html =    '<div class="cssload-container">\n' +
            '           <ul class="cssload-loader">\n' +
            '               <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>\n' +
            '           </ul>\n' +
            '       </div>\n' +
            '       <div class="modal-overlay"></div>';
    });
    </script>
```

when I click on the submit button then loading icon comes up and it goes away when the page finish loading.It happens at the time of the page load too. I am not sure how this loading icon goes away. I searched the entire page, but dont see any code that hides the loading icon. Can anyone suggest where should I look i the code to find out how the loading icon goes away once the page loads.

Comment: the part of the DOM that contains the image is probably updated.... so just inpect the page during and after the load to understand what has changed.  It's probably re-writing a parent element or even loading the entire page if it's a traditional page load.

Comment: Worth noting that the "mobileinit" event is fired before any other mobilejquery code runs. https://api.jquerymobile.com/mobileinit/

Comment: Check ajax call on form , there is option to set spinner image and once called completed spinner image disappear